# jQuery .prepend() Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

and I am trying to prepend an option value from a select. I need the output to start with a capital "K". Here is my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(".dialogbox").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
});
$(".dropdown").change(function () {
    $(".dialogbox").dialog("open");
    $(".dialogbox").change("puff");
});
$('select.dropdown').change(function () {
    var capacityValue = $('select.dropdown').find(':selected').data('capacity').toUpperCase();   
    $('.dialogbox').val(capacityValue);
});
```

});

and here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedimaster/qLFhj/6/)

I've tried

```
$('.dialogbox').val(capacityValue).prepend( 'K' );
```

but that didn't seem to work. All the examples I've seen indicate that this should work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code:

(1) `.prepend()` is for prepending an element as a child of another element. You are trying to call it on a string. I think you want to use string concatenation:

```
"K" + $('select.dropdown').find(':selected').data('capacity')
```

(2) You are missing an `=` in your html for the dropdown's "name" attribute:

```
<select class='dropdown' name='dropdown'>
```

(3) You have two elements with `class="dialogbox"`, so the following opens two dialogs:

```
$(".dialogbox").dialog("open");
```

You could either use two different class names, or include the element types in the selectors to distinguish between them: `'div.dialogbox'` & `'input.dialogbox'`

(4) You are attaching two `change` event handlers to the dropdown. There's no guarantee on the order they are called. You should combine them into one.

(5) You should use `.text()` or `.html()` to insert text into an element, not `.val()`. Use `.val()` just for setting the value of an input element.

(6) You can establish the animation effect for the opening of a dialog by including the `show` option:

```
show: 'puff'
```

Or:

```
show: { effect: 'puff', duration: 1000 }
```

---

Try the following:

```
$(".dropdown").change(function () {
    var capacityValue = "K" +  $(this).find(':selected').data('capacity').toUpperCase();

    $('div.dialogbox').text(capacityValue).dialog("open");

    $('input.dialogbox').val(capacityValue);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy728/2/)

Comment: So would I use .val() if I wanted to get the value of the selected option to store it's value so I could pass it to a PHP script?

Comment: @McFly - Yes, `.val()` is for getting and setting the `value` property of an input, and it works for getting the value of the selected option of a `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

.prepend() is to prepend a dom element. In your case just Try to prepend the text like this,

```
var capacityValue = "K"+ $('select.dropdown').find(':selected').data('capacity');
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLFhj/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your fiddle I think you don't undestand what prepend does. `capacityValue` it's just value of attribute.

.prepend

Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

`capacityValue` it is not element, it's object string, not more.

Comment: Please don't vandalize other answers.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I don't like when people change their answer accordingly with other. I won't =) I got it.

Answer (score 0):

**Reduced code to one line  and corrected it ! ****

```
    $('select.dropdown').change(function () {
     $('.dialogbox').val("k"+$(this).val());
    });
```

you can easily achieve it without prepend method

[solution is here](http://jsfiddle.net/qLFhj/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qLFhj/9/).

HTML:

```
<select class='dropdown' name 'dropdown'>
    <option data-selected='opts1' data-capacity='opt1' value='opt1'>Option 1</option>
    <option data-selected='opts2' data-capacity='opt2' value='opt2'>Option 2</option>
    <option data-selected='opts3' data-capacity='opt3' value='opt3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
<div class='dialogbox' title='Dialogbox'></div>
<input type="text" class="dialogbox" readonly />-->
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div.dialogbox").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("input.dialogbox").change(function () {
        $("div.dialogbox").dialog("open");
    });

    $('select.dropdown').change(function () {
        var capacityValue = "k".toUpperCase() +  $(this).find(':selected').data('capacity');
        $('div.dialogbox').text(capacityValue);
        $('input.dialogbox').val(capacityValue);
        $('input.dialogbox').change();

    });

});
```